# DataError: No numeric types using mean aggregate function but not sum?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I was wondering if someone could help explain the below behaviour using agg()

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string
```

**Initialise Data Frame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[list(string.ascii_lowercase)[0:5]*2,list(range(1,11)),list(range(11,21))]).T
df.columns = columns=['g','c1','c2']

df.sort_values(['g']).head(5)

g   c1  c2
0   a   1   11
5   a   6   16
1   b   2   12
6   b   7   17
2   c   3   13
```

*As an example I am summing and averaging across c1 and c2 while doing a group by g*

### No data error scenario:

```
f = { 'c1' : lambda g: df.loc[g.index].c2.sum() + g.sum(), 'c2' : lambda g: (df.loc[g.index].c1.sum() + g.sum())/(g.count()+df.loc[g.index].c1.count())} 
df = df.groupby('g',as_index=False).agg(f)
```

### Error with data type:

```
rnm_cols = dict(sum='Sum', mean='Mean') #, std='Std')
df = df.set_index(['g']).stack().groupby('g').agg(rnm_cols.keys()).rename(columns=rnm_cols)
```

I get the -> **DataError: No numeric types to aggregate**

I know if I initialise my data frame using the below I can avoid this issue:

```
df[['c1','c2']] = df[['c1','c2']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
```

> However I'm trying to understand why aggregating with the mean
>   function provides such errors ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the way `GroupBy` objects handle the different aggregation methods. In fact `sum` and `mean` are handled differently (see below for more details).

But the bottom line is that `mean` only works for numeric types which are not present in your data frame:

```
>>> df.dtypes
g     object
c1    object
c2    object
dtype: object
```

By applying `pd.to_numeric` you convert them to numeric type and the `agg` works.

But let's take a closer look:

#### [`GroupBy.mean`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/632204359249093d1305e71183be932ceceeee78/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1263)

This function call dispatches to [`self._cython_agg_general`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/632204359249093d1305e71183be932ceceeee78/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1006) which checks for numeric types and in case it doesn't find any (which is the case for your example) it raises a [`DataError`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/632204359249093d1305e71183be932ceceeee78/pandas/core/base.py#L166). Though the call to `self._cython_agg_general` is wrapped in `try/except` in case of a `GroupByError` it just re-raises and `DataError` inherits from `GroupByError`. Thus the exception.

#### `GroupBy.sum`

This function is defined in a different way, namely [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/632204359249093d1305e71183be932ceceeee78/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1431) (via [this function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/632204359249093d1305e71183be932ceceeee78/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1370)). The [wrapper function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/632204359249093d1305e71183be932ceceeee78/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1379) similarly dispatches to `self._cython_agg_general`, wrapped in `try/except`, but it doesn't add a specific clause for `GroupByError`s (no idea why though; maybe that's a good question for the developers, so they can unify the behavior of `GroupBy` objects). Because `self._cython_agg_general` again raises the `DataError` it will enter the [`except Exception`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/632204359249093d1305e71183be932ceceeee78/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1390) clause for which it falls back to [`self.aggregate`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/632204359249093d1305e71183be932ceceeee78/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L3408). From here you can trace it down through a dozen of additional function calls but in the end it will simply add the single items of the series (which are stored as `object`s but adding in Python is no problem since they are `int`s in fact).

#### Summary

So it all comes down to the different ways exceptions are handled by the two aggregation functions; `mean` re-raises on `DataError` but `sum` doesn't. The "why" still remains an open question to me as well.

#### See also

- [Inconsistencies in groupby aggregation with non-numeric types](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13416)
- [SeriesGroupby.cumsum raises on object dtype](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13992)

Comment: Thanks! that makes a lot of sense --- next time will drown deeper into the error

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this error very recently. Found out that while installing some package, my pandas was downgraded and was the cause for this error. Updated pandas and it started working fine.