# Pandas groupby.mean() giving me "No numeric types to aggregate" - but .sum() works

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working in Pandas in Python 3. For some reason, I can group by and then sum() my dataframe:

```
full_data.groupby('polarity')['pos'].sum()

polarity
both      1.842
neg       5.241
neu     496.026
pos     245.105
Name: pos, dtype: float64
```

When I swap out *mean* for *sum*, though, I get this error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Do you know why this would be the case? I've already confirmed that every item in the 'pos' column is a float, running the following code with no output:

```
for i in full_data.loc[:,'pos']:
if type(i) != float:
    print('not a float')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataError: No numeric types using mean aggregate function but not sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091321/dataerror-no-numeric-types-using-mean-aggregate-function-but-not-sum)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sum` and `mean` behave differently.  Consider these examples:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['a', 'b', 'b'], 'val': [1.2, 2.3, 3.4]})


In [3]: df.groupby('key').val.sum()
Out[3]:
key
a    1.2
b    5.7
Name: val, dtype: float64

In [4]: df.groupby('key').val.mean()
Out[4]:
key
a    1.20
b    2.85
Name: val, dtype: float64

In [7]: df.dtypes
Out[7]:
key     object
val    float64
dtype: object
```

Now if I change the `val` column such that it as a dtype of object:

```
In [8]: df['val'] = df.val.astype(object)

In [9]: df.groupby('key').val.mean()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b46b3a9673d0> in <module>()
----> 1 df.groupby('key').val.mean()

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in mean(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1304         nv.validate_groupby_func('mean', args, kwargs, ['numeric_only'])
   1305         try:
-> 1306             return self._cython_agg_general('mean', **kwargs)
   1307         except GroupByError:
   1308             raise

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_c
ount)
   1054
   1055         if len(output) == 0:
-> 1056             raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
   1057
   1058         return self._wrap_aggregated_output(output, names)

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

In [10]: df.groupby('key').val.sum()
Out[10]:
key
a    1.2
b    5.7
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Notice that `mean` no longer work for that column

The dtype of the column has nothing to do with the dtype of the individual cells, for example:

```
In [12]: isinstance(df.val[0], float)
Out[12]: True
```

Therefore, please check your column dtype and convert that to numerical.

---

Now why by design `mean` and `sum` behave differently, because `sum` should be allowed to act on non-numerical data, such as `str`, as long as summation makes sense for that data type.

```
In [14]: df['val'] = ['z', 'y', 'x']

In [15]: df.groupby('key').val.sum()
Out[15]:
key
a     z
b    yx
Name: val, dtype: object
```

Obviously, `mean` would make no sense for `str`.  Therefore there is an additional [`try-except` block](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1067) for `sum` to make it work for non-numercial data.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. I was unaware that the dtype was unrelated to the type of the cell objects. Much appreciated!